# Monodevelop curly braces (or brackets) and ALT keypad numbers

Tags: character, monodevelop, curly-braces

Good day all,

I realize this is an ugly subject, but I'm desperate to find a solution since this bug is barring me from using javascript in the editor.

Basically, the only way I can type the curly braces { and } is to use their corresponding numeric keypad codes, ALT + 1 2 3 and ALT + 1 2 5, however when I press ALT and a number, monodevelop will just jump to the open script in the current window, where ALT 1 switches to the leftmost script.

To add insult to injury, code templates don't work either. If I right click the editor area and select 'insert template' from the context menu, nothing happens! Additionally, the shortcuts window doesn't even have an "ALT + number" combination, so I can't get rid of it to see if that's the cause of the problem!

I am thus practically unable to use monodevelop to code with javascript, so I am here hoping that anybody knowledgeable with monodevelop can explain what's the problem, or propose a workaround (I've read about code snippets or other advanced functions, but without more insight can't tell if they can help me or not).
I am using monodevelop 2.8.2, but I've tried 2.6 and the problem is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through much indirect searching, I've found out that there's an additional 'special key' combination, consisting in

```
ALT GR + SHIFT
```

Specifically, `ALT GR + SHIFT + [` or `]` will output `{`  or  `}`.
Hopefully this might help some of you with a similar issue.